# Eclipse gluon new project does not finish

Tags: java, eclipse, gluon

I use Eclipse 4.7 (Oxygen), portable version

- Android Development Tools (no version ?), with SDK Manager => SDK Tools 25.5, Android 6 and 7 (API 23, 25), Android Support Repository, SDK Platform, SDK Platform-tools
- Gluon plugin 2.4.0
- E(fx)clipse 2.4.0
- Gradle IdePack 3.8.x +1.0.x
- SceneBuilder installed and configured in Eclipse
- and (MarketPlace, Enide 2015)

**new Gluon project begins well:**

- name and location (default)
- Gluon Application Settings (default)
- Name of view (default)
  => button finish appears active, **but when pressing it, nothing happens. This window blocks here** and no message. Only back button, close and cancel work.

I'v tried any combination of projects (Desktop, Mobile, single view, multiple, Fxml), and checkbox, but it doesnt change anything.

Have anyone encounter the same problem ?

Or is there any log to search for anywhere ?

thanks

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is still under development and won't be finally released until June 2017. Some of the other things you are using may not have been tested with Oxygen.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks - It's not clear there: https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-neon-portable/ - I'll try with previous version Neon.

Comment: still doesnt work tho, which is a shame...

Comment: @Xerus It does, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin has been updated (version 2.5) to work with Eclipse Oxygen and Gradle 2+. Install the new plugin (it will uninstall the old one) and it'll work again. See [here](http://gluonhq.com/upgrading-open-sourcing-gluon-plugin-eclipse/) for details.

Comment: It did not work for me on mac:/ That finish button is still bugged

Comment: @lelelo the OS shouldn't matter but you can file a bug with them.

Comment: If you are using buildship version 2.2.0+, you should make sure to use plugin version 2.5.3+. For more details - https://github.com/gluonhq/ide-plugins/issues/6

Answer (score 1):

i had the same error with Neon and it all boiled down to an exception i saw in the `.log` File of eclipse ({yourWorkspace}.metadata).

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.SynchronizeGradleProjectJob cannot be found by com.gluonhq.eclipse.plugin_2.4.0
```

It seems version 2.x of Buildships Gradle has rearranged its packages and contents making the finish button unclickable.

I downloaded the latest 1.x version from an updatesite which can be found on [github](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/blob/master/docs/user/Installation.md#installing-from-eclipseorg-update-site)  and everything runs just fine.

Hope this helps,

Bests!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, sorry for my english.

I was having the same problem as the [guillaume girod-vitouchkina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5387592/guillaume-girod-vitouchkina). I could not create a new Gluon project. I was using Eclipse Neon.2 and update for Eclipse Neon.3 and the problem persisted. So I did what [uBreckner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4349288/ubreckner) recommended and it worked! I uinstall version 2.x of Buildships Gradle and install latest 1.x version.

Thanks guys,

Regards!