# Workaround for creating Gluon projects without falling back to previous Buildships?

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I was trying to create a new (test) Gluon Single View Project to discover a compiling error with my team's iOS app. This was using the latest Buildships version 2x for Eclipse 4.7 Oxygen on Mac OS X 10.12.5.

Got to the last step of creating the project and the Finish button was unresponsive. Eclipse Error Log (pictured) showed "Unhandled event loop exception."

Thankfully, this SO question ([Eclipse gluon new project does not finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953287/eclipse-gluon-new-project-does-not-finish)) pointed me in the right direction, and I was able to:

**1) uninstall Buildships 2x**

2) install an old Buildships version from a third-party Github directory

3) make progress on my original task

Is this something being handled on the Buildships developer end, and is there a temporary workaround to reverting to an old version?

Comment: Until the plugin gets updated, there is no other workaround for now, as the new Buildship 2+ breaks the compatibility with Buildship 1.0.+, which is the one bundled with the plugin.