# Can not create a Gluon project with Eclipse

Tags: gluon

I am trying to create a new Gluon project.

I start the wizard, choose "Gluon mobile" and go through required steps.

When I reach this step and hit finish nothing happens.

[image: screen shot of problem]

Comment: Have a look at this [question[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171101/workaround-for-creating-gluon-projects-without-falling-back-to-previous-buildshi), there is a workaround if you are using Eclipse Oxygen with Buildship 2+.