# Error on Gluon Mobile

Tags: java, android, javafx-8, gluon-mobile

My eclipse has the following error when trying to create a GLUON project:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.buildship.core.projectimport.ProjectImportConfiguration.toFixedAttributes()Lcom/gradleware/tooling/toolingmodel/repository/FixedRequestAttributes;
    at com.gluonhq.plugin.eclipse.wizard.GluonProjectWizard.performFinish(GluonProjectWizard.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5268)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4522)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4107)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor115.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5268)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4522)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4107)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

Has anyone had this and solved it?

Comment: Strongly reeks of incompatible versions of libraries being mixed in the class path.

Comment: What can I do to eliminate this problem?

Comment: It's somewhere between the Gluon plugin and Eclipse itself (see the top 2 lines of the stack trace). Maybe it's not made for your Eclipse version? I'm not familiar with the details there

Comment: Which are your Eclipse and Gluon plugin versions?

Comment: Ok, the error was being generated, due to the gradle plugin being 2.0, gluon released a document stating this. I uninstalled Plugin 2.x and installed 1.x, solved the problem. Soon after, I did an update of it, and it kept working.

Thank you very much to everyone.

This error occurs in Oxygem 1.A

Comment: Actually, for Oxygen you can install or update the Gluon plugin to its 2.5.0 version, and you won't need to back port Buildship. See [this](http://gluonhq.com/upgrading-open-sourcing-gluon-plugin-eclipse/) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the error was being generated, due to the gradle plugin being 2.0, gluon released a document stating this. I uninstalled Plugin 2.x and installed 1.x, solved the problem. Soon after, I did an update of it, and it kept working. Thank you very much to everyone. This error occurs in Oxygem 1.A

[Eclipse gluon new project does not finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953287/eclipse-gluon-new-project-does-not-finish)