# How to set up Gluon for JDK 9?

Tags: gradle, java-9, gluon, version-compatibility

I recently upgraded to JDK 9 however Netbeans did not support that yet - so I downloaded Eclipse Oxygen. But I got into the problem [Eclipse gluon new project does not finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953287/eclipse-gluon-new-project-does-not-finish)

And using the latest Gradle Buildship plug in with the Gluon 2.5 - did not work for me (still having problem with finish button). I tried downgrading the Gradle Buildship to 2.1.2 and that allowed me to press the finnish button. However then gradle could not create gluon project - "gradle could not determine java version from '9.0.1'"

I downloaded IntelliJ IDEA and it did not work there either. I can also be mention I could run JDK 9 java projects in both Eclipse and Intellij as expected. In IntelliJ I found my jdk path not set. Setting it did not help. Then when I changed from using wrapper to local gradle, version 4.3.1 I could create a gradle project in Intellij - without getting the "gradle could not determine java version from '9.0.1'". That also allowed me to create a gluon project in intellij however...

"process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value"
... After trying to move jdk as I had two library folders, one in Mac ssd and one in home directory - of which did not work I tried with Eclipse again

There I went preferences and set gradle to local gradle to that same `4.3.1` version as I did in INtellij. Now the gluon project could be created. But when I run the `run` gradle task I then get same error as in Intellij "process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value"

Do I need to tell Gradle where to look for jdk or what is going on? And since: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1/24457 I already have Gradle updated I have no other choice but to ask for help.

This was done on a most recent updated mac - I have not tried yet on windows

Comment: I was trying to use jdk 9 with Gluon Mobile and that does not seem to ready yet - only Gluon for desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gluon VM Developer Preview has just been [released](http://gluonhq.com/gluon-vm-now-publicly-available-developer-preview-ide/).

This means that you have a new jfxmobile plugin version: 2.0.0, which allows running Java 9 on desktop and mobile.

The Gluon IDE plugin has been updated (check your IDE for the latest version), and there is a new template available: `Single View Project on Gluon VM`.

This template will generate a project with the required `build.gradle` file. Note that you can apply the configuration of this build file to the other templates or to existing projects.

You can also check the Gluon VM [sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/singleview-gluonvm) in GitHub. If you download it, you can:

- Run it on desktop with Java 8
- Run it on desktop with Java 9
- Deploy it on Android with Java 8 on your machine
- Deploy it on Android with Java 9 on your machine (*)
- Deploy it on iOS with Java 9 on your machine

(*) Android supports Java 8 API since version 24. It doesn't support Java 9 new API yet.

Note that the jfxmobile plugin version 1.3.10 from the other templates is still valid if you want to run/deploy projects with Java 7/8 as usual.

Comment: on https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/blob/master/README.md#android
stated that :
Note! Be aware that Java 9 APIs on Android are not supported. If you use version 2 of javafxmobile-plugin, you must make sure that you don't use any new Java 9 APIs.